# Removing Links from Projections only

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have a model like User which is being referenced in multiple places and therefore it has links pointing to associations. However, I want that I can get rid of the links in case of some Projections only for User. I have some projections which is for a very specific purpose exposing only a subset of columns. I tried using ResourceProcessor on Projection to call getLinks() and fiddle with it. But it seems that Links are appended after this since I could only find self link

I need some links however with projection which I myself have added to reflect the state.

Can this be achieved ?

Comment: I tried putting @Transient with Projection's getter methods for overriding but that kept the links since they are taken from Entity where they are not Transient